Calculating overlap of two arrays
I have two images representing densities of axons in a microscopy image, they both are 100x100 grids, I want to find a good way to calculate the overlap (or lack of) in these images, I have tried weighted jaccard index, which is good but I cant confirm the results of the jaccard index by eye, there must me something I am missing...
Are there any other good ways of calculating the overlap? Have a look at the image below:

